# Why does my tikz text appear behind my image?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i bring my text to the front of my image ? The code below puts it behind the image. I tell tikz node front but its still behind ?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,front] at (0,0) {some text};
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 3cm 0 0},clip]{figures/intro/intro1.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[fill=white, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0.5,0.2) rectangle (0.9,0.05);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of the statements so the text is set last; items are drawn sequentially within the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth,trim={0 3cm 0 0},clip]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      \draw[fill=white, ultra thick, rounded corners] (0.5,0.2) rectangle (0.9,0.05);
    \end{scope}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) {some text};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you friend !